# And condition for jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am developing a multipage form. I am trying to write an `if` condition:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    if ($('input[required]:visible').each().val() == false) {
        alert('Not all required fields are filled');
    } else {
        $('.next').show();
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('nextStep');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f50a5ymn/)

This works fine with `input type=text`. Then I am trying to add the same condition for `<textarea>`:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    if ($('input[required]:visible').val() == false && $('textarea[required]:visible').val() == false) {
        alert('Not all required fields are filled');
    } else {
        $('.next').show();
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('nextStep');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/f50a5ymn/1/)

Now it requires textarea OR input to be filled, but should work with both, shouldn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, you have content in the `textarea` (empty spaces). I think your best bet would be to trim the values before checking them and then comparing them to the empty string `''`.

```
if ($('input[required]:visible').val().trim() == '' || $('textarea[required]:visible').val().trim() == '') {
    ...
}
```

Also, I changed your `and` to an `or`, which is what I think you need.

Comment: Even I remove these spaces (they accidentally got there) this still doesn't work. But your solution worked fine! Even without .trim()

Comment: @SergeyYesin The point of the `trim()` command is that you don't have to remove them.

Comment: That is because `.val()` returns a `string`. An empty string should evaluate to false, though...

Comment: Can you please help with another issue? https://jsfiddle.net/f50a5ymn/8/

Comment: Don't you think .length is better than == '' ? I am taking in general not because my answer is not accepted.

Comment: @SergeyYesin You probably should post that as a new question, as this one is already marked as solved.

Comment: @MayurPatel The `== ''` comparison makes for clearer and shorter code. There's really no "better" here.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.val()` gives you the content of Textbox or Textarea, not Boolean. So you can use jQuery `.trim().length`. It will first remove the white space and then it counts the length of Textbox or Textarea.This ensures that even space is there, it will work. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f50a5ymn/5/)

```
$('.next').click(function(){

    if($('input[required]:visible').val().trim().length==0 || $('textarea[required]:visible').val().trim().length==0) {
        alert('Not all required fields are filled');
    }
    else{
         alert('All required fields are filled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `trim` the value before comparing.

Below is the code to handle required inputs (for checkbox, radio button different handling will require).

```
$('.next').click(function() {
      var valid = true;
      $.each($('[required]:visible'), function() {
         if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
             valid = false;
             return false;
         } 
     });

     if (!valid) {
         alert('Not all required fields are filled');
     } else {
         alert('All required fields are filled');
     }
 });
```